# Spring Boot - handling end of Apache Kafka queue

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a component class containing a method annotated with @KafkaListener. It's fine for applying logic for each and every message I consume from the queue but I need to manipulate a List when all the messages from the queue are consumed. How to proceed? Is there any event listening annotation or interfaces to implement? Thanks in advance for any answer

Answer (score 0):

The consumer is an event-driven pattern for a stream of events. Therefore it doesn't look like you are following the logic behind that `@KafkaListener`. If you are restricted with a limited number of records in the Kafka topic, consider to retrieve them using `KafkaTemplate.receive()`. This one indeed implements an `on-demand` pattern.

If you still stuck with the `@KafkaListener` and don't want to revise your logic, you may look into a `ListenerContainerIdleEvent` handling.

See more info in docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/receiving-messages/template-receive.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/events.html#idle-containers